# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.versions.node') while using cloudinary in nuxt 3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am using cloudinary in Nuxt 3 for uploading image. While using npm i cloudinary and using cloudinary it shows TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.versions.node') in console

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more effort regarding your question here? This is not enough context overall, a [repro] could be great.

Comment: I am using cloudinary in Nuxt 3 for uploading image. While using npm i cloudinary and using cloudinary it shows TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.versions.node') in console